# android app crashes when exceeded Thread pool 9 and queued tasks 128

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

The application conduction api calls in every 10seconds with the gps location from the network provider. And also there are several api calls can be do by the user.

application is crashing with law internet or less internet connection(device data access)
is there a proper way to prevent app crashing and hold the api request till the internet network available.

here im posting my crash reprort stacktrace

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: 
Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@4206a5b0 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41e97858[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 2]    
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)    
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:590)   
at com.pickme.driver.service.LocationUpdate$LocationUpdateTask$1.run(LocationUpdate.java:216)   
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711)     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you using kitkat or lower device to test the application? Try out android 5.0(lollipop)..

Comment: using kitkat and lower devices

Comment: For me, the crash was caused by this line: `new pingHTTP(connURL.get(i),i).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`.  This is my `FATAL EXCEPTION`: `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@bab00da rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4adf90b[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 1061] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:843)`.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya asyncloader is available now. please use async loader its handling the thread pool by it self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queued tasks = 128` indicates that you have reached maximum count of tasks for AsyncTask:

[private static final BlockingQueue sPoolWorkQueue =
   new LinkedBlockingQueue(128);](http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#193)

one aproach is to queue your jobs in some data structure, in example bundles and store it in some database (sqlite). It would be usefull anyway because if user will terminate your application, then now all your tasks are lost. If they are persisted in sqlite - then you can send them on next app run.

You could also use [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)), which has unbounded queue, but you would have to do any UI updates yourself - in example with handlers. AsyncTask-s implementation is based on Executors.

Comment: thanks for the immediate answering. is it possible im keep collecting my location points from GPS and stored in shared preferences when network available. And keep checking is network available. when then the network available create one json object and call api. please give me the pros and cons of my approach.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood about AsyncTask, AsyncTask implementation before kitkat can queue only 128 tasks. Above which it will issue `RejectedExecutionException`. So I would suggest you **reduce the number of AsyncTask created**.

Comment: thanks for the immediate answering. is it possible im keep collecting my location points from GPS and stored in shared preferences when network available. And keep checking is network available. when then the network available create one json object and call api. please give me the pros and cons of my approach. and please give me a proper way to avoid "RejectedExecutionException"